# Trigger - If time between?

Tags: mysql, trigger

I wish to use a mysql trigger that will update a column called peak to 0 or 1 based on if the CURTIME() is between 08:01 & 11:59.

Can anyone help with this trigger?

Comment: `create trigger tr before insert on mytable for each row set new.peak = curtime() between '08:01' and '11:59';`

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to triggers, if time was just base on a column value like a time that defaulted to CURTIME, a generated expression could be used:

```
create table dt (
  t time,
  peak bool generated always as (t between '08:01' and '11:59')
);
```

After inserting:

```
insert 
into dt(t) values ('8:00'),('8:01'), ('8:02'),('11:58'),('11:59'),('12:00');
```

The results are:

```
select * from dt;

| t        | peak |
| -------- | ---- |
| 08:00:00 | 0    |
| 08:01:00 | 1    |
| 08:02:00 | 1    |
| 11:58:00 | 1    |
| 11:59:00 | 1    |
| 12:00:00 | 0    |
```

Like a normal column, peak can appear in indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like that:

```
BEGIN
  IF CURTIME() BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '11:59:59'
    THEN UPDATE ...
  END IF
END
```

This trigger will be activated each time the event occure but it will do something only if current time is within the given range and will do nothing otherwise.

Comment: Along with the code, you write something about the functionality of the code.

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhan  I've add some explanation to the code.

Comment: I cant seem to get this working :- DELIMITER $$

    CREATE TRIGGER isPeak BEFORE UPDATE ON user_stats
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
      IF (CURTIME() BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '11:59:59') THEN
            SET NEW.peak = '1';
      ELSE
            SET NEW.peak = '0';
      END IF;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;